# SQL query returns "value too long"

Tags: c#, sql, db2, odbc

I have a SQL query that is supposed to fill a DataTable in memory but I get an error saying "Value 'Beginning of My value' is too long."

The query works in a SQL editor but not when I'm running it programatically with C#. Counting the value it appears do be at most about 38 characters long and at minimum 9. This isn't a lot which makes me confused as to what the issue might be? The SQL query is creating a dynamic table based off of data from other database tables with the help of subqueries.

The error returns a number (`SQL0433N and SQLSTATE=22001`) which directs me to this [explanation page.](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_9.7.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.messages.sql.doc/doc/msql00433n.html)

However it does not help me directly with my problem.

Some sample code, where `ImportSQLTable()` holds the SQL query string.

```
 OdbcDataAdapter da = new OdbcDataAdapter(ImportSQLTable(ID), DbConnection);
 DataTable dt = new DataTable();

 da.Fill(dt); // Fill the table with data from the query
```

Using .NET Framework 4.6.1

Comment: Edit the question to add details that will allow people to help you, the query, the DDL, your locale in C# and the Db2 database encoding/table-encoding. If the encoding differs between your application and the target-column then you can get this symptom (caused by difference between fixed-width encoding and variable-width encoding like utf-8).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to fix this by converting the column, which was showing the error, to a datatype with a length that I felt comfortable with.

The convertion looked like this:

```
SELECT CAST(MyColumn as varchar(100)) as MyNewColumn
```

EDIT: An additional way, or if this doesn't work as I experienced, is to use @"" When you store the string in C#. Looks like this:

```
public string mySQLString()
{
    return @"
             SELECT col1, col2, col3
             FROM MyDatabase
             WHERE col1 = 'mytext'
            ";
}
```

I don't know exactly why, but by changing to this the error of a too long value disappeared!

Comment: Often this come up  when I work tables that have large text columns.